# Ingesting LARGE CSVs to file geodatabase to create feature class and then clipping?

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, csv

I am trying to convert 30 .csv files that have ~50,000,000 records each, and are just over 3gb each, to point feature classes within a FGDB.

If I do this one by one by hand, I generally right click in ArcCatalog > Create Feature Class > From XY Table--this takes a while but works.  Unfortunately I cannot call that tool from arcpy when trying to automate this--doesn't exist to my knowledge.  I wrote the script below to automate the ingest.  It works on small files, but fails on these large files.

Any advice?

Willing to explore other tools.

```
import csv
from itertools import islice
import os
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
fgdb = r'C:\_L\Cols.gdb'
clip_features = r'C:\_L\MS.gdb\Polys'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\_L\Samples'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".csv"):
            fullFilePath = os.path.join(subdir, file)
            print fullFilePath
            fileName = os.path.basename(fullFilePath) #filename with extension
            fileNameNoExt = os.path.splitext(fileName)[0] #filename without extension

            arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(fullFilePath, 'Field3', 'Field2', fileNameNoExt)
            arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fileNameNoExt, fgdb + "\\" + fileNameNoExt)
            #arcpy.Clip_analysis(fgdb + "\\" + fileNameNoExt, clip_features, fgdb +"\\"+ fileNameNoExt + "_clip")
            print fullFilePath
```

Comment: What are your computer specs? Could you please add the error message? Are you using 64 bit background geoprocessing? http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/64bit-background.htm

Comment: I loaded 50 files that totaled 300m rows over and over again last summer, but the target was a PostgreSQL database, not FGDB. Python has a `csv` module, which works great, but not if the files are UTF-8.  DA InsertCursor is quite robust, and performed well, provided that high I/O performance  was available. Depending on the width of the files and the I/O subsystem, I would expect your load to run for 50 to 500 hours. I would question the need to use file geodatabase for files over 20m rows and wouldn't recommend concatenating them in one table.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clarify if the files are independent or to be concatenated, the version of ArcGIS involved, and provide your reasoning for not using a *real* database to manage 1.5 gigarows. Please also explain further your "then clipping" intention, since manual load could conditionally insert, obviating the need.

Comment: it would be easier to just loop through the files and insert the info into a postgres table

Comment: What version of ArcGIS are you using?  In this case that may affect the tools available to you.